# Azure durable orchestration function doesn't exist, is disabled, or is not an orchestrator function

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-durable-functions, azure-container-registry

Azure Durable HttpStart failed at `client.start_new(req.route_params["functionName"], None, None)` function call.

Function app works local develop environment, even in docker container. Once it's deployed to Azure Kubernetes Service, HttpStart function failed to start Orchestration Function.

Log trace:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.DurableFunctionsHttpStart
 ---> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException: Result: Failure
Exception: Exception: The function 'DurableFunctionsOrchestrator' doesn't exist, is disabled, or is not an orchestrator function. Additional info: No orchestrator functions are currently registered!
Stack:   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 338, in _handle__invocation_request
    call_result = await fi.func(**args)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/DurableFunctionsHttpStart/__init__.py", line 16, in main
    instance_id = await client.start_new(req.route_params["functionName"], None, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/durable_functions/models/DurableOrchestrationClient.py", line 82, in start_new
    raise Exception(exception_message)
```

System overview:

```
Function runtime: 3.0.2630
Python version: 3.7.7
azure-functions: 1.3.1
azure-functions-durable: 1.0.0b9/1.0.0b7
Kubernetes version: 1.17.11
Node size: Standard_DS2_v2
OS type: Linux
```

Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:3.0-python3.7

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true \
    WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=<ip-address>:<port>

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
```

Reproduction scenario:

1. Create a Durable Function HttpStart App from VSCode.
2. Use `func init --docker-only` command
3. Docker command `az acr build --registry yourRegistryName --image durableFunction:v1 .`
4. Deploy in AKS `func kubernetes deploy --name durableFunction --namespace yourNameSpace --service-type ClusterIP --registry yourRegistryName`

Funcation app starts normally but when failed in http post request. However, this same contaninarized function app, works in Azure Hosted Function App.

There is an similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/577) was reported two years back, but it's happening now.

Comment: The linked GutHub issue doesn’t seem to be related to the problem you’re seeing. In your case it looks like none of your Durable triggers are being recognized.

Comment: Where u able to fix this issue? I am facing a similar issue.